# Library Accessing Hieararchy

Tags: java

In which order jar files is taking.. i have Oldversion jar file along with jdk lib and new version in tomcat lib. which one the class loader takes..
1.Inside JDK lib
2.Inside tomcat lib

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the classloader and the settings you use. Probably it's your application's lib then tomcat finally jdk, but as said it depends.

Edit: if you have several versions of one jar in the same library it might also depend on how the JVM returns files which often is not deterministic. Therefore in most cases it's not a good idea to have multiple versions of a library in the same directory.

Comment: You won't remove jars from the jdk. As I said, it's not a good idea to have multiple versions of the same jar in _one_ location, but you normally can have them in several hierarchy levels when using the appropriate class loader settings.